# Read running processes' virtual memory from mm_struct in linux

Tags: process, linux-kernel, crash, system-calls, proc

I'm trying to write a kernel module that uses the proc file system to read the total memory of each running process. This is for an assignment and it is suggested that use the information of the "mm_struct" which is inside " "task_struct". I should compare the output of content of the proc file with what I obtain from running "ps -ef".  I'm using the seq_file API to read from the proc file. My current read function looks like this:

```
static int proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v){

   struct task_struct *task;
   /*struct mm_struct *mm; Commented this since it's inside task_struct
    *struct vm_area_struct *mmap; Commented this since it's inside task_struct */ 
   unsigned long size; 

    for_each_process(task){
      seq_printf(m,"Task = %s    PID = %d\n",task->comm,task->pid);     
      down_read(&task->mm->mmap_sem);       

      if(task->mm){
         size = (task->mm->mmap->vm_end - task->mm->mmap->vm_start );
         seq_printf(m," VIRT = %lu\n",size);            
      }else{
         seq_printf(m," VIRT = 0\n");
      }
      up_read(&task->mm->mmap_sem);
   }
return 0;
}
```

The message "Killed" is promted as soon I try "~# cat proc/my_proc_file". So far what I think I now is that vm_area_struct is inside of mm_struct which is inside task_struct, all of them defined in the include /linux/sched.h.

A similar question, which is the one I partially based this code on, was posted by @confusedkid (see the post [Linux Kernel programming: trying to get vm_area_struct->vm_start crashes kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481678/linux-kernel-programming-trying-to-get-vm-area-struct-vm-start-crashes-kernel)). However the replies contradict each other and no one actually explains the reasoning behind the code.

Could anyone please point out what the problem might be or suggest any documentation that explains how to access these structure correctly?

Comment: Reason of the "Killed" should be contained in the kernel log (`dmesg`). `However the replies contradict each other` - Really? The [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2481700/3440745) on referenced question tells that you need to check `mm` field for being non-NULL before dereferencing it. Almost all other answers also have note about this check.

Comment: Yes, and actually I'm checking for mm in the if condition of my code: if(task->mm){
         size = (task->mm->mmap->vm_end - task->mm->mmap->vm_start );

Comment: You perform `down_read(&task->mm->mmap_sem)` before checking `task->mm`.